# SCNNode detached from its SCNPhysicsBody

Tags: swift, scenekit

I have a SCNNode which has its physicsBody set like so:

```
let randomVector = SCNVector3Make(0, 100, 0)  
node1.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()  
node1.physicsBody!.applyForce(randomVector, impulse: true)
```

However, when this runs, the SCNNode moves erractically in one direction, but the Physics outline moves as expected.

Is there any reason as to why they would seperate?

I can see this in debugging with:

```
scnView.debugOptions = [.ShowPhysicsShapes]
```

Comment: Could we have some more code? A minimally reproducible test case that works in a playground?

Comment: Hi Hal, I'll take apart my project and post back when I can.